# Chef SSL verification failed while setting workstation

Tags: ssl, chef-infra

I am setting up Chef workstation by configuring knife.rb using "knife configure -i" configure command. After PROPERLY answering all question, I get the following error :

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: 172.xx.x.xx - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
ERROR: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

My goal is to disable this SSL certificate verification forever and use knife utility to bootstrap my all nodes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. You should probably ask this question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: In his defense, Chef questions get a lot more attention here than they do in super user or serverfault

Comment: Checkout the following blog article. http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/ Recommends the use of the knife ssl fetch plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue running chef-client after upgrading to the version 12.xx. Steps to solve:

1. Pull crt from server. Run on node:
   knife ssl fetch  -s https://yourchefserver01.com:443
   Note: If fetch doesnt work copy from yourchefserver01.com:/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/yourchefserver01.com.crt to client:/root/.chef/trusted_certs/yourchefserver01.com.crt
2. Verify it pulled:
   knife ssl check  -s https://yourchefserver01.com:443
3. export SSL_CERT_FILE="/root/.chef/trusted_certs/yourchefserver01.com.crt"
4. Run chef-client

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the validation of the chef server certificate. 
Install a proper certificate on the chef server

or add your chef server certificate (located in `/etc/chef-server/hostname.crt`) to your workstation `cacert.pem` (located by default in `<install path>/opscode/chef/embedded/ssl/certs`).

With chef 12 you'll have to ditribute it too on your nodes to validate the chef API server or you'll have a warning at the start of each chef-client run about it.

Comment: You could also cheat and switch off SSL validation. Naughty but simpler. See the ssl_verify_mode setting in the client.rb file: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html

Comment: But you'll have a warning at start of the chef run in this case, with an enforcing of ssl validation announced...

Comment: I said for chef 12, but it's also true with 11.16.x versions for the warning part

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be concerned with the .pem validator. your validation are misconfigured. Try create new validation key from chef server and place it under the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Chef Server on-premise, it will easier in the long run to install a third-party SSL cert, e.g. Verisign, on the Chef Server (or load balancer). `chef-client` and `knife` come with OpenSSL which will trust a valid third-party cert automatically with no configuation required on each node.

Please don't turn off SSL cert validation. SSL validation is additional protection that the server you are trusting with root access to your Chef nodes is the real Chef server, not a man-in-the-middle attack.